# React Native Constant Layout on Multiple Devices

Tags: layout, react-native

I have a minimal app with basic views, texts, images and buttons in react native. The problem I am facing, is in managing layout for multiple devices. 
Any suggestions on how can I maintain a same (proportionate) view & font size for multiple devices (multiple screen resolutions and screen sizes).

View:
For example, if I want a list view of items, where each row has one image on the left, some text in between and 2 buttons on the right (one below the other i.e. `flex-direction: 'column'`), how can I have this look good on a 5" device as well as a 10" device?

Also, consider the buttons have some `borderRadius`, if we are scaling the buttons, the `borderRadius` value will also need to be increased. How do I achieve this?

Fonts:
I have tried using `PixelRatio.getFontScale()` but this scales the font depending on only the resolution (from what I understood). Using this, makes a font of size 12 look bigger on a 5" device with higher resolution and smaller on a 10" device with lower resolution. So how can I manage font sizes for the react native app?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `PixelRatio.getFontScale()` you can also use the `Dimensions` API to get the height and width of the window, and scale your components relative to that. I have built an app that runs on both iOS and android and use this to scale width's + heights.

Checkout the link [Dimensions @ Facebook - React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html#content)

ie.

`Dimensions.get('window').width;
  Dimensions.get('window').height;`

Will return you the size of the window

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to use both? I had tried using them individually, but didn't get the expected result.

Comment: [This Medium post](https://medium.com/@elieslama/responsive-design-in-react-native-876ea9cd72a8#.hi8cgrp8d) gives a good description of using Dimensions API to modify layout based on device width.

Answer (score 0):

How about this library? [react-native-scaled-layout](https://github.com/mym0404/react-native-scaled-layout)

You can use scaled dimensions for your layout margin, height, padding ...

```
(36).scaled() /* or */ (36).d() 

(36).widthScaled() /* or */ (36).w()

(36).heightScaled() /* or */ (36).h()

(24).fontScaled() /* or */ (24).f()
```

```
style={{
    width: (100).w(),
    height: (210).h() + safeAreaBottom,
    borderRadius: (16).d(),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingBottom: safeAreaBottom + (24).h(),
}}
```